# Peer to Peer transfer on LoL

Tags: league-of-legends

What is it and should I disable it. Also does it share data from my computer to other users and use my internet (Which is already really slow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you are uploading game files to other users who are downloading them from you, very similar to how torrents work. If you don't wish to host game files for other users to download, you should disable it. It will likely slow your upload speed which may also hurt your net bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

The LoL installer used Pando Media Booster to distribute files via p2p [prior to patch 4.3](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=45475976#45475976) (Riot reference), I had asked about it earlier: 
[How can I identify games that use Pando Media Booster, and is there a workaround to download the installer without it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76527/how-can-i-identify-games-that-use-pando-media-booster-and-is-there-a-workaround)

The latest version no longer uses PMB but they haven't got around to unbundling it from the installer. Pando 1.3 now has a new owner, and I read rumors about them now doing some borderline shady stuff like changing IE home page etc. - and since its not being used anyway, you should certainly uninstall it.

It used to share data using your internet connection, while LoL doesn't do so any more I am unsure if leaving Pando installed may lead to using up bandwidth.

Comment: Interesting info, but that doesn't really answer the question about what P2P transfer means.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to what has already been said, If you are experiencing lag in your game and you have absolutely nothing working in the background then this (the peer to peer option) is highly likely the cause and you should disable it.